# org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional vs javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional

Tags: java, spring, jdo

When using spring `@Transcational` on service layer, I will need to put `<annotation driven>` on xml file.

I'd like to know

1. Can `javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional` be used on service layer just like spring does? Without needing to configure xml files. etc?
2. Can `javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional` be used on service layer independent of whether I use hibernate/jpa/jdo at the dao layer? Do I need to configure any other things beside marking methods with `@Transactional`?
3. Are there any differences/limitations between `javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional` and `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you look at the javadoc? This is what I read about [`javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional`](http://db.apache.org/jdo/api22/apidocs/javax/jdo/annotations/Transactional.html):

> Annotation to indicate that a member (field or property) is transactional but not persistent. This corresponds to xml attribute persistence-modifier="transactional" of "field" and "property" elements.

This doesn't seem comparable with the [`@Transactional`](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.0/api/org/springframework/transaction/annotation/Transactional.html) annotation from Spring.

> Describes transaction attributes on a
>   method or class.
>
> This annotation type is generally
>   directly comparable to Spring's
>   RuleBasedTransactionAttribute class,
>   and in fact
>   AnnotationTransactionAttributeSource
>   will directly convert the data to the
>   latter class, so that Spring's
>   transaction support code does not have
>   to know about annotations. If no rules
>   are relevant to the exception, it will
>   be treated like
>   DefaultTransactionAttribute (rolling
>   back on runtime exceptions).

So, to answer your questions:

> may i know can `javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional` be used on service layer just like spring does? do not need to configure xml files. etc?

No.

> can `javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional` be used on service layer independent on whether i using hibernate/jpa/jdo at the dao layer? need to configure any other things beside marking methods with `@Transactional`?

No. See above.

> any different/limitation between `javax.jdo.annotations.Transactional` and `org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional`?

Yes. One is an apple, the other an orange.